# Disconnecting a Laravel Connection

Tags: php, laravel

I am having some trouble with disconnecting my created conn.

```
$dbName = session("key")["db_name"]["0"]->main_db;

$oldEmail = $this->connection()->table("tbl_user")->where("id",$UserID)->get();

DB::disconnect($dbName);

$User = User::where("email",$email)->get();
return $User;
```

I think the connection bypass my model and search for the table name of "User" in my created connection, I don't get the error, though it has the same name in my migration.

This is my codes in generating another connection:

```
public function connection() {
    // SESSION
    $dbName = session("key")["db_name"]["0"]->main_db;

    // MAKE CONNECTION
    Config::set("database.connections.".$dbName, array(
        "driver"    => config("app.DB_CONNECTION"),
        "host"      => config("app.DB_HOST"),
        "database"  => $dbName,
        "username"  => config("app.DB_USERNAME"),
        "password"  => config("app.DB_PASSWORD"),
    ));
    DB::setDefaultConnection($dbName);
    $conn = DB::connection($dbName);

    return $conn;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: iam using my model as a connection, for example User::all(); now before I do that, and user my connection() it will not use my model anymore, it will just find user in my connection

Comment: this issue was fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> app/config/database.php

```
  return array(

    'default' => 'mysql',

    'connections' => array(

        # Primary/Default database connection
        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
            'database'  => 'database1',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => 'secret'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

        # Secondary database connection
        'mysql2' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
            'database'  => 'database2',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => 'secret'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
      ),
  );
```

**Useful Links**

- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/laravel-5-multiple-database-connection